# NextJS route shows [slug] in url

Tags: reactjs, next.js, routes

I have a NextJS app with the folder structure:

```
- pages
  - docs
   - [slug]
     - index
     - [id]
       - index
```

These pages are supposed to be dynamic based on the data that appear in the UI. Meaning a user can go to /docs/payments/introduction (where **payments** and **introduction** are dynamic pages too).

However everything works fine when the user is one level deep in the nesting eg (docs/payments), but when the user goes 2 level deep (eg docs/payments/introduction), all the links begin showing [slug] in their url. Let's say there's a link in the sidebar that's supposed to go to `/docs/payments/faq` it then starts showing `/docs/[slug]/faq` in the url.
[Here's a screenshot of an example url](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RMb6U.png)

I have no idea how its happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `[...slug].tsx` to be able to use multiple slugs.

```
- pages
  - docs
   - [...slug].tsx
```

If you want more info, click [here](https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/dynamic-routes#catch-all-routes).

Comment: Thanks Nicolae, this was exactly what i needed. There was even no need to add another [id] folder.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are using `Link`s and `router.push`es correctly? When using dynamic slugs, you should use `as` prop. Like this:

```
<Link as="/page/docs/getting-started/creating-an-account" to="/page/docs/[slug]/[id]">
  <a>Link</a>
</Link>
```

or if you are using `router`, like this:

```
const router = useRouter();

router.push('/page/docs/[slug]/[id]', '/page/docs/getting-started/creating-an-account');
```

Comment: This looks good too, what i missed was basically the [...slug] catch all pattern. Cha ged it and it works fine now. Thanks